# Munchkin - can you put cards which you cannot use sideways

Tags: munchkin

In the card game of Munchkin (or Munchkin Zombie) I've seen people put some cards on the table sideways. Usually, they can't use those cards for some reason like it's not for their class or they exhausted body parts limit.

They do that, so they could trade cards, that they cannot use.

Is it used to distinguish equipped and carried items?

The rulebook that came with the game (in the Polish language) does not cover this kind of behaviour.

Edit: For the base version of the game, there is a new one available online which has this covered. Also, all rulebooks in English include this rule.

Comment: Afaik it is covered in the rule book, but I could remember wrong. I do this, too, and these "tapped" cards are supposedly in your backpack.

Comment: @Erik you are right, all current rulebooks in English contain this rule. My mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be a standard part of the rules for [Munchkin](https://munchkin.game/site-munchkin/assets/files/1138/munchkin_rules-1.pdf) for Item type cards.;

> All **Items** you have in play are considered “carried.” **Items** that are actually
> giving you a bonus are “equipped.” You should indicate **Items** that are not
> equipped by turning the cards sideways. You may not alter the status of your
> **Items** during a combat or while running away

For rules for more specific expansions, the parent page of the link above is [loaded](https://munchkin.game/gameplay/rules/).

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the rules only specify this for Items (not for Races or Classes).

Comment: @Raj, yes it is just for items, I will highlight that.